# Ubuntu switched to classic mode after install ccsm and enable OpenGL

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-unity

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and I have installed ccsm for advanced effects and enable OpenGL (ATI graphic card), but then my windows doesn't have bar and I cannot open anything. When I start Ubuntu I am switched to classic. What to do to return Unity ? I tried sudo aptitude remove ccsm, but didn't help. Can someone give me advice ?